# Проблема авторизации в Elma с помощью python

Tags: python, c#

Делаю авторизацию в Elma на python столкнулся с такой проблемой как в этой теме(https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-api/thread2994497.html), но там ее так и не решили. У меня ошибка такая же. В документации к Elma есть пример работы с авторизацией, но там на С#, поэтому не понятно как передавать пароль. В ответ должен прийти токен.

Пример работы с c#( https://www.elma-bpm.ru/KB/article-5613.html)

> {'InnerException': None, 'Message': 'Ошибка авторизации', 'StatusCode': 401}

```
        elma_host = '188.234.251.210:8000'
        elma_app_token = 'пример токена'
        elma_user = 'имя'
        elma_password = 'пароль'


        elma_url = '''http://188.234.251.210:8000/API/REST/Authorization/LoginWith?username=имя'''

        elma_request_headers = {'ApplicationToken': elma_app_token,
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

        elma_request_params = {'password': elma_password}
        response = r.post(url=elma_url, params=elma_request_params, headers=elma_request_headers)
        print(response.json())
```